# How to use scrollTo

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scrollto

My package.json:

```
      ...
      "scripts": {
        "build": "gulp && webpack",
        "webpack": "webpack"
      },
      ...
      "dependencies": {
        "scrollto": "git://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo.git" // ???
      }
      ...
```

my backbone view:

```
const Backbone = require('backbone');
const _ = require('underscore');
const $ = require('jquery');
require('scrollto'); // ???
...
  _handleError(error) {
    if (error) {
      $('#header').focus();
      $(window).scrollTo('#header'); // ????
    } else {
      ...
    }
  },
...
```

Command:

```
gulp && webpack
```

Error:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'scrollto' in /home/me/src/myproject/src/dashboard/static/js/views/query
```

Anything missing or wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Fixed:
    "jquery.scrollto": "^2.0.0"

```
require('jquery.scrollto');
```

Comment: Why require scrollTo? Isn't it apart of the jquery library?

Comment: @evolutionxbox You are right. I just found it. Thanks